# How to integrate an email classification model into Outlook?

Tags: email, machine-learning, outlook, nlp, text-classification

Let's say I built an email classification model which classifies email into two classes A and B. Is it possible to link this model to Outlook and make this classification automatic; whenever I recieve a new email it gets sent to folder A or B in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct link with the Outlook object model. You need to develop a VBA macro if you don't have any plans to distribute your solution on multiple machines or a COM add-in if you need to deploy it to other machines. In the code you could handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. So, you may call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

So, as soon as you have the item you can get property values to make a decision where to move that item and then call the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method to get it done. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) to get started quickly.